# MVC3 Json Bind Bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I recently encountered an issue while implementing a JSON solution for a client. If the action parameter name matches a property  name of the model, the binder fails to bind ANY properties.

An example:

Controller People

```
public ActionResult SetEmails(Person emails){
    ...
    return Content("");
}
```

Because the parameter name was called "emails" and that matches a property name of the Person model called "Emails".. the binder fails, but does not give any indication as to why..

They had a model called Person

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Emails { get; set; }

    public Person() {
        Emails = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or a 'feature' ?

Just as a side note, my question is more in regards to how an arguments name could cause a conflict to a binder? The name shouldn't matter as it's the class type that defines it's schema to match against the json data.. why should the binder care what you name the argument or if it matches a property name within the class type of the argument itself?

Comment: can you post the calling js code, or at least the JSON you are submitting?

Comment: json would be:

{"Name":"John", "Emails":["test@test.com", "test2@test.com"]}

The json was fine, as i stated, once i changed the Actions argument name from Emails (matches the models property name) to anything that didn't match, it worked.. I just thought it was interesting and can't see why this shouldn't work, or at the very least throw an exception instead of a instantiated class with null property values!?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have an ambiguity in your dictionary, with two elements both named "emails" (though with different casing).  `DefaultModelBinder` cannot resolve this ambiguity.

Two possible solutions:  (1) if you are passing back an entire person model, change the name of your top-level element to "person" (which makes more sense, given the context), which would remove the ambiguity, and allow the binding to take place as expected, or (2) if you are just passing back a list of emails, change your action signature to `public ActionResult SetEmails(List<Emails> emails)`.

I would not call what you have experienced either a bug or a feature, but an issue with your design.

Comment: I switched it to person, which solved the issue. The name isn't a requirement, I was just taking on legacy code and my last thought as to why the model binder would fail was that the Action argument name matched a property name of the arguments class type.

I don't get why this would cause any Ambiguity? emails.GetType().GetProperties() etc.. match them up against the json coming in.. if an arguments class type (schema i suppose) matches that of the json, great.. what does the argument name matter? How does the name come into play during the binding? It's name doesn't dictate it's class type!

Comment: JSON is bound through the `DictionaryValueProvider`, so the values are associated through key names.  If there are two keys of the same name, the Dictionary will not be valid.  Please mark as answered if this was helpful.

Comment: And those keys should come from the classes properties, not the name that you gave to the argument that is used to bind your model. 

How does the parameter name have any relevance when iterating over it's properties? 

var pi = controller.GetMethod("action").GetParameters();

How here, do you require the name of the parameter or how does it influence the outcome of retrieving the parameters at which point you can then get it's class type and iterate over it's properties to bind the data.

It's not a question of two properties having the same name (invalid and wouldn't compile)..

Comment: Examine the code for `DictionaryValueProvider`, and you will see where the issue comes up.  The backing store created by `JsonValueProviderFactory` containing the JSON values creates a dictionary key named "Emails" for the JSON element named "Emails."  When your action tries to bind a variable named "emails," the DictionaryValueProvider will pull the "Emails" key and try to bind against that key.  Since the type of the key does not match, there is a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying I *like* this for an answer, but you CAN avoid changing your property name.

Wrap your JSON object with the variable name of the parameter (in this case, it's "emails"). So this works:

> data: JSON.stringify( { emails: { Name: "my name", Emails: ["a@a.com",
>   "b@b.com"]} } );

but this doesn't - the modelbinder returns null instead:

> data: JSON.stringify( { Name: "my name", Emails: ["a@a.com", "b@b.com"]} );

Still, this is pretty crappy. However things work deep under the covers, there's no reason my web client should have to know what the parameter name in the controller is in order to work correctly. As far as I'm concerned, it's a bug in MVC's modelbinder.